# Postprocessing.py error when running TauDEm on new machine

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2.18, taudem

When running any operation using the TauDEm provider I get the following errors and no output raster file is produced.

```
2018-07-06T10:19:55 0   TauDEM execution console output
2018-07-06T10:19:55 2   Error loading result layer:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\Postprocessing.py", line 77, in handleAlgorithmResults
                isRaster)
              File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 186, in load
                + '\nCheck the processing framework log to look for errors')
            RuntimeError: Could not load layer: C:\Users\DAVID~1.LAV\AppData\Local\Temp\processing43e2c87d54c34dc48591433ce19aeb4e\879e56b7c22445d6881832ccfde7ae20\fel.tif
            Check the processing framework log to look for errors
```

I have uninstalled qgis and re-installed a fresh install after deleting my qgis2 folder and also everything I could find in the registry. I have installed 2.18.14 as this was the version I had before my computer went up in smoke yesterday.

This new computer is also running Windows 10 as my previous one.